# design pattern(GoF patterns) implementation in c++

Tags: c++, design-patterns

What are the elegant design pattern(GoF patterns) implementation in c++ ?

Can anyone give me some examples of design pattern implementations based on template(which can be reused) ?

Example(Template based Singleton) :-

```
template<typename T>
class Singleton : public boost::noncopyable
{
public:
    static Singleton& GetInstance()
    {
        boost::call_once(&CreateInstance, m_onceFlg);
        return *m_pInstance;
    }
    virtual ~Singleton()
    {
    }
protected:
    Singleton ()
    {
    }
    static void CreateInstance()
    {
        m_pInstance.reset(new T());
    }
private:
    static boost::once_flag m_onceFlg;
    static boost::scoped_ptr<T> m_pInstance;
};
```

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily call a C++ singleton implementation based on boost very elegant...

Comment: Uh, read the GoF book? Most of the examples in the book are C++.

Comment: @Andreas Grapentin Qt people don't prefer to use boost library. Here I have given an example.

Comment: @PherricOxide Those are basic examples which is difficult toreuse

Comment: It is unfortunate, but patterns are more useful as a tool to describe a design or capture the behavior of a software system rather than as actual building blocks of an implementation. That said, you might want to take a look at [the Adaptive Communication Environment](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE-overview.html).

Comment: I think most patterns use polymorphism and just cannot be templated easily. Patterns are not a library, you should apply them, not 'reuse'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, there are really no good design pattern template libraries. A design pattern is difficult to capture correctly as a concrete template without caveats or imposing difficult to enforce restrictions on the classes that try to plug themselves into it.

Let's take your `Singleton` example. Well, I'm actually going to rewrite it so that I don't have to have Boost to use it:

```
template <typename T>
class Singleton {
    Singleton (const Singleton<T> &) = delete;
    Singleton & operator = (const Singleton<T> &) = delete;
    static Singleton<T> & GetInstanceInternal () {
        static T instance;
        return instance;
    }
protected:
    Singleton () {}
    ~Singleton () {}
public:
    static T & GetInstance () {
        return static_cast<T &>(GetInstanceInternal());
    }
};
```

Although this makes `Singleton<T>` a singleton, what is really wanted is to make the `T` a singleton. Well, you might say, this is no problem, because the usage is that `T` should inherit from `Singleton<T>` (as enforced by `Singleton::GetInstanceInternal()`):

```
class Foo : public Singleton<Foo> {
public:
    void foo () { /*...*/ }
};
```

A naive programmer would think "Job done!", because since `Foo` inherits from `Singleton<Foo>`, that makes `Foo` a singleton. But it doesn't, because it doesn't prevent this:

```
Foo x;
```

To fix this, the constructor should be made private (and therefore, `Singleton<Foo>` needs to be made a friend). To prevent calling the destructor directly, it should be made private as well.

```
class Foo : public Singleton<Foo> {
    friend class Singleton<Foo>;
    Foo () {}
    ~Foo () {}
public:
    void foo () { /*...*/ }
};
```

So, in addition to inheriting `Singleton<Foo>` there are additional requirements that inheritance alone cannot properly enforce. All these requirements can be documented, but it can be argued that using the templates become less useful, and it is almost as much work as putting the singleton functionality into `Foo` directly.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Modern C++ Design by Alexandrescu

[http://www.amazon.com/Modern-Design-Generic-Programming-Patterns/dp/0201704315](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201704315)

He covers template implementation of several design patterns. In fact, IIRC, one of the forewards is written by one of the GOF.