# Creating singleton subclasses

Tags: c++, inheritance, singleton

I'm currently building a game in C++ which handles updating, input, and rendering via a stack. The `StateStack` contains states (`MenuState`, `PauseState`, `GameState`, etc.) which all inherit from the `State` class, and are pushed onto and popped from the stack based on choices made by the user.

To avoid trouble I would like to make the subclasses of `State` singletons, and to that end it would be convenient to inherit singleton-ness from `State` in such a way that it wouldn't require implementation in `State` subclasses. I can't think of a way to do this without running into unwanted collision between the subclasses (a `GameState` instance disallowing construction of the `PauseState`, for example). Is there a way to do this cleanly, or should I begrudgingly resort to using an abstract virtual implementation in `State`?

Comment: Relevant: [Template singleton base class in shared object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22998019/template-singleton-base-class-in-shared-object/22998472#22998472). Using a CRTP will lead you in the right direction. I have made a template framework for what you want to achieve, BTW: [STTCL](http://makulik.github.io/sttcl/)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That is crazy slick. Definitely giving it a shot. Love how that works for pretty much any class, too...

Comment: As a counter point to @πάνταῥεῖ, consider that [template frameworks have limitations](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18497963/315052).

Comment: @jxh Take a closer look, STTCL covers a lot of details in the FSM/State Pattern problem domain.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, the covering of a lot of details is one of the hard things about using a framework. If you want to tweak one of those details covered, it requires a deep understanding of how the framework was implemented.

Comment: @jxh Well, good frameworks have some learning curve. Though I'm tending to abstract out policy based design decisions, by simpler usage of _selector_ template parameters, that just choose from an enum.